# What happens if broken cfl stays in the room for few months?

Tags: bulb, cfl

cfl bulb broke in a open box.I don't know when did happened ,anything from year and few months.I cleaned the box and safely disposed all but I don't know if rest of the room would be contaminated from vapor that is released.Does vapor stay in the air or does it settle like dust on the surfaces in the room?

Comment: Probably cut down on eating fish for a while.  You were exposed to a tiny winy amount of mercury.  Might be a concern if you broke a hundred a day, everyday.  Vacuum and dust the room if concerned.

Answer (score 1):

The mercury vapor would normally leave the house, dissipate into the air within a week. On an immediate break, It is suggested that one leave the room for 15 minutes after opening a window, then clean up the glass and finally vacuuming the area and wiping furniture down. After a few months, only the glass would remain. The room has probably been cleaned and vacuumed so cleaning up the glass would be all that's needed. If it helps you sleep at nigh, clean up the room again. The amount from a single CFL would not be enough to get anyone sick.